# Create matrix of lead variables

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have 20x1 dataframe df and am adding adding a 20x3 matrix of lagged variables to it. Would also like to add a 20x3 matrix of lead variables. How can I achieve that? Thank you very much.

```
df <- data.frame(Close = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))

n <- NROW(df$Close); m <- 3                  #how many bars bck to check
LagMatrixClose <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = m) #pre-allocate
LagMatrixClose <- matrix(unlist(data.table::shift(df$Close, 1L:m)), ncol=m)
dimnames(LagMatrixClose) <- list(rownames(LagMatrixClose, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = ""),
                                 colnames(LagMatrixClose, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "LagC"))
df <- cbind(df, LagMatrixClose)
```

---

EDIT/UPDATE: The following code adds such matrix of lead variables, yet it uses a `for` loop, which I would rather avoid for efficiency purposes, as this is to be applied to a large data frame to create not just 3 lead variables but hundreds instead. Can someone think of an alternative?

```
rowShift <- function(x, shiftLen = 1L) { 
  r <- (1L + shiftLen):(length(x) + shiftLen)
  r[r<1] <- NA
  return(x[r])    }

n <- NROW(df$Close); m <- 3                   #how many bars bck to check
LeadMatrixClose <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = m) #pre-allocate
for(i in 1:3) { LeadMatrixClose[,i ] <- rowShift(df$Close,+i) } 
dimnames(LeadMatrixClose) <- list(rownames(LeadMatrixClose, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = ""),
                                 colnames(LeadMatrixClose, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "LeadC"))
df <- cbind(df, LeadMatrixClose)
```

This is how the final output with the lagged and lead matrices both created and added to df looks like:

```
   Close LagC1 LagC2 LagC3 LeadC1 LeadC2 LeadC3
1   1221    NA    NA    NA   1220   1220   1217
2   1220  1221    NA    NA   1220   1217   1216
3   1220  1220  1221    NA   1217   1216   1218
4   1217  1220  1220  1221   1216   1218   1216
5   1216  1217  1220  1220   1218   1216   1216
6   1218  1216  1217  1220   1216   1216   1217
7   1216  1218  1216  1217   1216   1217   1220
8   1216  1216  1218  1216   1217   1220   1219
9   1217  1216  1216  1218   1220   1219   1218
10  1220  1217  1216  1216   1219   1218   1220
11  1219  1220  1217  1216   1218   1220   1216
12  1218  1219  1220  1217   1220   1216   1217
13  1220  1218  1219  1220   1216   1217   1218
14  1216  1220  1218  1219   1217   1218   1218
15  1217  1216  1220  1218   1218   1218   1207
16  1218  1217  1216  1220   1218   1207   1206
17  1218  1218  1217  1216   1207   1206   1205
18  1207  1218  1218  1217   1206   1205     NA
19  1206  1207  1218  1218   1205     NA     NA
20  1205  1206  1207  1218     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Thanks David! That's exactly what I was looking for! Solved my problem in one line of code rather than multiple, and without using the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table::shift` functions `n` argument accepts a vector and also can run both `lead` and `lag` transformations. So this should be both pretty straight forward and vectorized

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.6
m <- 3    
setDT(df)[, paste0("LagC", 1:m) := shift(Close, 1:m)]
df[, paste0("LeadC", 1:m) := shift(Close, 1:m, type = "lead")]
df

#     Close LagC1 LagC2 LagC3 LeadC1 LeadC2 LeadC3
#  1:  1221    NA    NA    NA   1220   1220   1217
#  2:  1220  1221    NA    NA   1220   1217   1216
#  3:  1220  1220  1221    NA   1217   1216   1218
#  4:  1217  1220  1220  1221   1216   1218   1216
#  5:  1216  1217  1220  1220   1218   1216   1216
#  6:  1218  1216  1217  1220   1216   1216   1217
#  7:  1216  1218  1216  1217   1216   1217   1220
#  8:  1216  1216  1218  1216   1217   1220   1219
#  9:  1217  1216  1216  1218   1220   1219   1218
# 10:  1220  1217  1216  1216   1219   1218   1220
# 11:  1219  1220  1217  1216   1218   1220   1216
# 12:  1218  1219  1220  1217   1220   1216   1217
# 13:  1220  1218  1219  1220   1216   1217   1218
# 14:  1216  1220  1218  1219   1217   1218   1218
# 15:  1217  1216  1220  1218   1218   1218   1207
# 16:  1218  1217  1216  1220   1218   1207   1206
# 17:  1218  1218  1217  1216   1207   1206   1205
# 18:  1207  1218  1218  1217   1206   1205     NA
# 19:  1206  1207  1218  1218   1205     NA     NA
# 20:  1205  1206  1207  1218     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not look elegant, but should work. We can always create the lag and lead function, but with three lags and leads, this should be fine.

```
df <- data.frame(Close = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))

df$lag1 <- c(rep(NA, 1), head(df$Close, -1))
df$lag2 <- c(rep(NA, 2), head(df$Close, -2))
df$lag3 <- c(rep(NA, 3), head(df$Close, -3))

df$lead1 <- c(tail(df$Close, -1), rep(NA, 1))
df$lead1 <- c(tail(df$Close, -2), rep(NA, 2))
df$lead1 <- c(tail(df$Close, -3), rep(NA, 3))
```

EDIT: For the general case,

```
# Functions
add.lag <- function(x, n.lag, col.id) {
  for (i in 1:n.lag) {
    x[paste0("lag", i)] <- c(rep(NA, i), head(x[[col.id]], -i))
  }
  x
}

add.lead <- function(x, n.lead, col.id) {
  for (i in 1:n.lead) {
    x[paste0("lead", i)] <- c(tail(x[[col.id]], -i), rep(NA, i))
  }
  x
}

# Apply functions
df <- add.lag(df, 3, 'Close')
df <- add.lead(df, 3, 'Close')
```

Comment: Thank you. I do need the general case though. Only the simplified example is for leading 3 rows, in reality need to create quite a large lead values matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the result should look like, but here is a building block using dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(Close = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))

require(dplyr)

dplyr::lag(df$Close, n=1)
[1]   NA 1221 1220 1220 1217 1216 1218 1216 1216 1217 1220 1219 1218 1220 1216 1217 1218 1218 1207 1206

dplyr::lead(df$Close, n=1)
[1] 1220 1220 1217 1216 1218 1216 1216 1217 1220 1219 1218 1220 1216 1217 1218 1218 1207 1206 1205   NA

df_lags <- data.frame(sapply(1:3, function(nl) {dplyr::lag(df$Close, n=nl)}))
df_leads <- data.frame(sapply(1:3, function(nl) {dplyr::lead(df$Close, n=nl)}))
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Ideal when wanting to create separate lag/lead matrices  (i.e. not as part of source matrix). Will be using this. Thanks.